# How to autopopulate multiple drop downs using jquery ,json

Tags: jquery, json

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ybqsl.png)What I have done:
I have created multiple drop downs dynamically.On select of any options in this drop down another drop down has to be auto populated.Their are multiple number of drop downs for which auto population has to be done.

Issue facing:
It is working correctly for the first drop down . But when I select the option from next drop downs then also it auto populates the options in first auto populated drop down.

JSP:

```
enter code here


  $(document).ready(function(){
<%String subAction=(String)request.getAttribute("subAction");
ArrayList<String> fieldNameList=(ArrayList<String>)request.getAttribute("fieldNameList");
  int noOfFields=(Integer)request.getAttribute("noOfFields");
if(subAction!=null && subAction.equals("view") ){%>

   $("#home").hide();
  $("#returnedFromServlet").show();
  <%}
else{%>

$("#home").show();
  $("#returnedFromServlet").hide();

<%}%>
$("#returnedFromServlet").load(function(){
  alert("Image loaded."); });


       $(".selectType").change(function(){
    $.get('Upload', {subAction:'autoPopulate',ctype:$(this).val()},function(responseJson) {  
             var html;
            var $select = $('#autoPop');  
            $.each(responseJson.arrayName, function(index,value) { 

             html += '<option name="'+value.id+'" >'+value.name+'</option>';      
            });
         $select.html(html);
        },'json');
       }); });
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylSdl.png)

Servlet :

```
            JSONArray cellarray = new JSONArray();
             JSONObject cellobj = null; //new JSONObject();
             JSONObject jo=new JSONObject();
            // String country=request.getParameter("countryname");  


                 for(String s: populateFields){
                     cellobj = new JSONObject();
                     cellobj.put("id", option);
                     cellobj.put("name", s);
                     cellarray.add(cellobj);
                 }  
                 jo.put("arrayName",cellarray);
                 response.setContentType("application/json");
                 response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
                 response.getWriter().write(jo.toString());
```

Comment: Post your hmtl. the line where you get the $select will most likely always be the same select input field as you're selecting on an ID, i.e. 'autoPop'. So every time that piece of code runs, it selects the same select tag and populates it.

Comment: I got the problem however I am not getting how to assign unique id to dynamically generated multiple drop downs.Can u please tell me how to do this.

Comment: I can;t unless you show me how you generate your dropdown menues.

Comment: I have uploaded the screen shot.

Comment: Could you explain how that code generates the drop downs? I don't think that is jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post html. I think the problem is this line

```
html += '<option name="'+value.id+'" >'+value.name+'</option>';
```

You need to delete data in 'html' variable after the one select polluted.

Comment: I think u have not understood my question clearly. Can u pls give me he mail id ,so that i can explain the question using screen shot of output clearly.

Comment: hey enesxtufekci@gmail.com

Comment: If any one knows pls answer the question .